# Extract date from excel file name in python

Tags: python, pandas

My excel file is named: event summary - show_20121011.xlsx

and I want to extract the date and put to new column as event date.

So far what I have done is

```
xls = event summary - show_20121011.xlsx
event_date = xls.split("_"[1]
```

but what I get is 20121011.xlsx

how can I get the date only?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` with lookbehinds & lookaheads to extract the date between `_` and `.xlsx`

```
import re

xls = 'event summary - show_20121011.xlsx'
pattern = r'(?<=_).*(?=\.xlsx)'

re.search(pattern, xls).group(0)
```

Output:

```
'20121011'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xls = event summary - show_20121011.xlsx
event_date_with_extension = xls.split("_")
even_date = event_date_with_extension.split(".")
print(even_date[0])
```